# How to change programmatically Quick Action image/colour from inside an AppleScript

Tags: applescript, automator

I am working on a Quick Action in Automator to mute/unmute a mic on a MacBook. The quick action is then assigned to Apple Touch Bar so the mic can be easily toggled from anywhere.

[image]

What I am having problem with is to programatically change the button colour. When the mic is disabled I want to change the colour to black. While when the mic in enabled I want the colour of the button to be red.
[image]

The colour of the button is stored in the action 'plist' file. My idea was to edit the file from inside the script. However editing the file does not take effect. When I change the colour of the button from Automator, it re-creates the entire action, what refreshes the button.
The other option I am considering is to have 2 buttons - one for enable the mic (black) the other to disable it (red). The script would have to assign/deassign the right action button.